# Evitar id duplicados em lista c#

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo um exercício de lista em que tenho que inserir o id do funcionário, mas não deve haver repetição de id. Gostaria de saber como usar o `foreach` para evitar fazer a verificação e barrar caso seja inserido um valor repetido.

Segue o código da classe executável:

```
Console.WriteLine("Quantos empregados serão registrados?");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        List<Empregado> lista = new List<Empregado>();

        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Empregado #{0}",i);

            Console.WriteLine("Digite o ID:");
            int id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            foreach (int obj in lista)
            {
                if (id!=null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Id já existe, digite outro:");
                    id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                }
        }
```

Comment: E não pode ser feito de outra forma? Tem alguma restrição do que pode usar?

Comment: perguntei ao professor e ele respondeu isso:"O que você pode fazer é percorrer a lista para saber se já existe o id que está sendo informado. Para isso, você pode fazer um laço foreach na lista para realizar essa validação, beleza?"
Mas não entendi como fazer isso.

Comment: Mas essa é uma forma ruim de fazer, existe alguma restrição?

Comment: se houver uma maneira mais fácil pode ser tbm, só queria saber como fazer para evitar a duplicidade mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Vou te mostrar uma forma que pode alcançar oque deseja fazer.

Dessa forma você consegue usar o **Linq** para verificar se o id digitado já existe na sua lista:

```
//Usando linq para verivicar se o id digitado já existe na sua lista
if (lista.Any(x=> x.Id == id))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id já existe, digite outro:");
    i--; //Se existe, decrementa o contador para que ele possar informar novamente
}
else
{
    //Adicione aqui seu novo Empregado a sua Lista
}
```

Caso você ainda não tenha aprendido sobre [Linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries) e você não entenda oque está fazendo, tente continuar sua implementação utilizando o `for` ou `foreach`. É importante que você entenda oque está fazendo.

Note que no seu código na pergunta existem problemas e nem a implementação com o `foreach` você alcançou.

Aqui por exemplo: `foreach (int obj in lista)` você está tentando percorrer sua lista do tipo `Empregado`, mas está setando ela como `int`. Isso não funcionará.

Outro problema, menos grave é esse: `if (id!=null)` onde seu id é do tipo `int` e nunca será `null`. [Leia aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) se quiser entender mais sobre isso também.

Comment: acho que não é o caso de linq pela grade dele, mas você está selecionando todos os ids da lista, convertendo pra um array, depois faz um Where onde vai retornar todos os itens da lista se o array conter o id informado, depois converte isso pra outra lista, e checa se a quantidade é maior que 0... complicou em... basta:  `if (lista.Any(x=> x.Id == id)) { }`

Comment: @Rovann Linhalis Ia recomendar exatamente isso, mas quando venho no comentário vejo que já o fizeram.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, editei com a forma que sugeriu se não se importar. Muito mais simples mesmo.

Comment: O listaIds ficou desnecessário ali George.